# Windows - Android SDK manager not listing any platforms or packages to install

Tags: android, sdk, package-managers

After I have installed the Android SDK using the exe file available and the Android SDK manager has opened, I cannot see any of the additional packages that are needed to be installed. All that is listed is the Android SDK Tools under the Tools folder. The Extras folder also doesnt display anything under it. So without this, I am stuck right in the beginning. The log messages that I get also doesnt exactly point me to anywhere. Following are the log messages that I get:

**Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Done loading packages.**
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: im having the same problem now, tried the options to check for proxy also no luck

Answer (score 4):

If your problem hasn't already been solved, try setting the proxy server from the SDK manager under the Tools -> Options menu. This is the mistake I had made. Perhaps this might help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because I was running SDK Manager from eclipse. The menu does not even have a Tools -> Options option. If this is the case just run the installed SDK Manager from your programs

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your firewall, it works for me